# Local equation numbering inside proofs

Tags: equations, numbering, environments, counters

According to the question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29267/which-equations-should-be-numbered) and a possible suggestion to the problem which equations should be numbered given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49079/97026) I want to ask following question;

I find it a good solution to number all equations outside a proof-environment for a later reference option. I also share the opinion that equations inside a proof only have a local character, which do not need a global numbering. But I think one is limited to manually use `\tag{$\ast$}` on those equations inside a proof which one refers to. In case one restructures a proof, one has to manually change all tags and on the other hand I think it looks silly to have an equation tagged with (****).

Therefore I would like to know if it is possible to have a local equation numbering only for the proof-environment, i.e. to achieve a local numbering inside proofs for equations for which one refers to inside a proof. The numbering should start for every proof from the beginning in alphabetical style (a), (b), (c) and so on and to have a global counter outside proofs.

I guess there might exist some complications since I use cleverref. So it would be good to have a solution to this problem compatible to cleverref. Furthermore I would like to use all typical formula environments like equation, align, gather etc. just with a local counter inside proofs.

Comment: So you'll never refer to an equation inside a proof from outside the proof?

Comment: If one I want to refer to an equation inside a proof from outside a proof I make it a global statement. Thus reference from outside of proofs should not happen.

Comment: Are you using any package to create your proofs? Like [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)? What about [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: I am using `amsthm`to create proofs and `hyperref`as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make temporary redefitions at the beginning and end of environment with the help of hooks provided by the `etoolbox` package.  So a first attempt is:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,etoolbox,cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcounter{equationstore}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:one}
  x = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Proof
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:p}
    a = b
  \end{equation}
  refers to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and \eqref{eq:p} and gives
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:q}
    c = d
  \end{equation}
  as required.  Note the cleveref references are \cref{eq:one},
  \cref{eq:two} and \cref{eq:p}.
\end{proof}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:two}
  z = 2
\end{equation}
Refer to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and \eqref{eq:p}.  Note the
cleveref references are \cref{eq:one}, \cref{eq:two} and \cref{eq:p}.


\end{document}
```

This needs to be adjusted depending on you equation labelling scheme.

If you are using `hyperref` you can avoid messages about duplicate labels either by disabling the `hypertextnames` option or as follows, where the `\theHequation` is also redefined in a way that includes a unique number for the current proof:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcounter{equationstore}
\newcounter{proofnum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}
\refstepcounter{proofnum}
\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\alph{equation}}
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{\arabic{proofnum}.\alph{equation}}}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:one}
  x = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Proof
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:p}
    a = b
  \end{equation}
  refers to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and \eqref{eq:p} and gives
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:q}
    c = d
  \end{equation}
  as required.  Note the cleveref references are \cref{eq:one},
  \cref{eq:two} and \cref{eq:p}.
\end{proof}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:two}
  z = 2
\end{equation}
Refer to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and \eqref{eq:p}.  Note the
cleveref references are \cref{eq:one}, \cref{eq:two} and \cref{eq:p}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: If I take your MWE and load the following packages in this order, `\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,etoolbox}, \usepackage{hyperref}\usepackage{cleveref}` and compile it with pdflatex, then I obtain following error: `pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.2}) has been already used, duplicate ignored`. I guess hyperref makes some trouble. I still obtain this error commenting out the cleveref-part. Moreover the reference-system seems to be disturbed in the final pdf-document.

Comment: OK.  That info was not in your question.  See my update to my answer to cover this.

Comment: Works for my thesis-project with `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}`, no errors. But with errors enabling hypertexnames. In the MWE it works with enabling hypertexnames as well. So I would say my problem is solved, but is there something dangerous about loading hyperref in this way?

Comment: `hypertextnames=false` is not dangerous, but it just means the internal links names no longer have obvious meaning to a human (they may show up when you hover over them with a mouse).  Redefining `\theH...` make a more comprehensible version and avoids the problem.