# Number only referenced equations for local equation numbering

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, numbering, environments, counters

In this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290018/local-equation-numbering-inside-proofs) I asked to achieve a local equation numbering for equations which appear *only* inside proofs and to have a global counter for equations outside of proofs. I prefer the style where equations inside proofs are numbered with a star, i.e. (1*),(2*) or (3*a) and so on. This can be managed in the following way:

```
%
% Local equation numbering inside proofs
%

\newcounter{equationstore}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}${}^\ast$}}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}}
```

As you can see there exist two equation counter. Before entering the proof environment, the *global* counter is stored, then switched to another *local* counter, which starts from zero for each proof environment. After exiting the proof environment the *global* equation counter is loaded.

I would like to know if it is possible to show only those equations inside proofs which one refers to inside a proof. Equations inside proofs will be only referenced from the same proof. A solution should respect that I use `hyperref`. `cleveref` is NO longer necessary for me.

Comment: I could look into that later today I think; there's `mathtools`' `showonlyrefs` (see `mathtools` documentation), but AFAIK this change is global. Have you got a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to spare please?

Comment: @yo' -- The `showonlyrefs` option of the `mathtools` package is seriously incompatible with `cleveref`. :-(

Comment: @yo'-- A MWE can be taken from Andrew Swann right here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290019/97026

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hyperref` solution I gave to the other question works fine with `mathtools`' option `showonlyrefs` provided you drop `cleveref`, which is a standard caveat for this option of `mathtools`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcounter{equationstore}
\newcounter{proofnum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}
\refstepcounter{proofnum}
\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}$^*$}
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{\arabic{proofnum}.\arabic{equation}$^*$}}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:one}
  x = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{theorem}
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Proof
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:p}
    a = b
  \end{equation}
  refers to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and \eqref{eq:p} and gives
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:q}
    c = d
  \end{equation}
  as required.
\end{proof}

\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:two}
  z = 2
\end{equation}
Refer to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and \eqref{eq:p}.


\begin{theorem}
  A second theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
  Proof
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:p2}
    a = b
  \end{equation}
  refers to \eqref{eq:one}, \eqref{eq:two} and gives
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:q2}
    c = d.
  \end{equation}
  \eqref{eq:q2} is the required result.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

For your new request of applying the reference-use check only to equations inside proofs, you can adjust the above code to

```
\newcounter{equationstore}
\newcounter{proofnum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}%
\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}
\refstepcounter{proofnum}
\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}$^*$}
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{\arabic{proofnum}.\arabic{equation}$^*$}}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}%
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=false}}
```

Comment: I have to uncheck this answer, since finally I came a across a misbehavior of the solution. What I want is to have  `showonlyrefs` for referenced equations inside proofs, with a new counter for every proof, but on the opposite to display all equation numbers outside proof-environments (includes the non-referenced ones). I could use `\noeqref` for all equations outside proof-environments, but this is merely a workaround.

Comment: EDIT: Maybe one can switch on 'showonlyrefs' when entering a proof and switch it off at the end?

Comment: Is this okay?

`\newcounter{equationstore}
\newcounter{proofnum}

\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}\setcounter{equationstore}{\value{equation}}
\refstepcounter{proofnum}
\setcounter{equation}{0}\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}$^*$}
\renewcommand{\theHequation}{\arabic{proofnum}.\arabic{equation}$^*$}}
\AtEndEnvironment{proof}{\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=false}\setcounter{equation}{\value{equationstore}}}`

Comment: Yes, that works.  I'll mention it in my answer.